# How to paste an image to Excel from C# which is able to be copied

Tags: c#, image, excel, copy, zedgraph

I'm busy making an application which can measure all kind of things. The results during the measurement are displayed in a graph using the ZedGraph.dll.

After a measurement I want to export some "screenshots" of the graphs to Excel, this works fine. Except for one issue, the images are not selectable in Excel. You can't do anything with them. Is there any way to fix this problem?

The code I used:

```
// Export panes
OneCel = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[row, col];
Clipboard.SetDataObject(zgcRGB.MasterPane.GetImage(550, 500, 400f));
xlWorkSheet.Paste(OneCel, misValue);
```